# Regular level set of two nearby functions on a compact

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ be such that $0$ is a regular value of $f$. For each $K \subset U$ compact, there is $\epsilon_K$ such as $0$ is a regular value of $g|_K$ if $|g(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon_K$ and $|Dg(x) - Df(x)| < \epsilon_K$ for $x \in K$.

I've been struggling with this question for days. For the case that $f^{-1}({0})$ does not intersect $K$ is obvious, and I can understand that $g^{-1}({0})$ should be close to $f^{-1}({0})$ if $|g(x) - f(x)|$ is small enough (then I can control the derivative so that $g^{-1}({0})$ is a regular set). But I'm stuck in actually proving this. Can someone give me a tip?